# GCS bucket should be accessible from only specific people

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have created one GCS bucket in my GCP project where i will save some html files. Users will access that html files from browser using object URL.

I want that html url to be accessible from only specific people who belong to my organization. Even if someone from outside hits that URL, data should not be accessible to them.

Whats the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In ([1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)) you can find the two available methods for controlling the access to the objects inside your Google Cloud Storage buckets:

-**Uniform**: You will provide access to different users depending on the IAM roles you grant to them ([2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)). All of the objects inside the same bucket will share the same policy (you can also define a group of objects with the same prefix instead of the whole bucket)

-**Fine-grained**: Apart from the IAM roles, you can also use Access Control Lists ([3](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists)) for defining special policies for each object. This way, a user can have access to only some of the objects inside your bucket.

Once you have defined the appropriate policies according to the desired permissions to be granted to each user, you will need to share with them the Authenticated URL of the object and, according to the GCS UI, "Only users granted permission can access the object with this link".

On the contrary, If you would like to make an object publicly available for everyone in the Internet, you can follow ([4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)) in order to create a Public URL for a certain object. This is also depicted in ([5](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)):

> Most of the operations you perform in Cloud Storage must be
> authenticated. The only exceptions are operations on objects that
> allow anonymous access. Objects are anonymously accessible if the
> allUsers group has READ permission.

Comment: Thanks @rodvictor,  from the statement "Only users granted permission can access the object with this link"  ,, do you mean that , if i give "cloud object viewer" permission to specific user in GCS bucket. only that user can hit URL of objects in that bucket?

Comment: It does not have to be exactly the role `cloud object viewer`. From my understanding, anyone with a role which includes the permission `storage.objects.get` will have access to that object's data. You can check in `https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions` the specific permissions needed for each type of interaction with the object. If you want to be 100% sure, you can set the desired policy and then try to access to the authenticated link of the object from incognito mode with another gmail account!

Comment: i tried to give "cloud object viewer" permission to myself. but when i try to hit the URL, i get  "Forbidden Error 403".

Comment: Same URL i can access if i give same permission to allUsers / allAuthenticatedUsers.

Comment: It depends on at which level you are being given this permission. For example, you can click on the name of a bucket which has Uniform Access Control, then click on `permissions` and then on `add`. If you give here the role `Storage Object Viewer` to yourself, you should be able to access any object inside that bucket

Comment: I have given uniform access to bucket and give storage object viewer access in two ways:
1. by clicking on three dots at right side of bucket name
2. by clicking on bucket name and then permission tab.
Still getting forbidden error